# Sim300 not responding to atmega32

Tags: gsm, atmega

My sim300 gsm module isn't responding to atmega32, I have connected as described in the schematics ,and have used some headers for setting up usart settings, despite all that there is no response from gsm, what am I doing wrong?

Sim300 works because I tried calling the number and it works!

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. It seems while working in atmel studio you need to add a symbol that defines the frequency of the crystal.
All that was required to do was add a symbol F_CPU=16000000
and it started to respond.